# Journey builder "Error binding data bound member"

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, error, contact

I'm facing the hard error situation from a Decision split activity in a Journey builder. (after activating a journey)
The criteria in this split is set by 'logged in' value, more specifically, the value we can check on Mobilepush demographics on All contact.
We asked for a support and they said it typically happens when the contacts are not registered in all contacts, but it isn't the case.(all contacts used in journey were properly registered.)
Can anybody share experiences regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone needs this in the future, I'm posting an answer here even if the question was asked months ago.

We have faced the exact same problem, and it's a [known issue in Journey Builder](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwbpAAC/journey-builder-decision-split-fails-using-mobilepush-demographics-attribute-group).

We've asked the support, and the solution was "re-priming", which is, according to them:

> The re-prime is just like rebooting the schema within a specific
> attribute group, if there is any issue like a missing or altered
> default attribute or relationship with that schema the reprime can
> correct it.

And this actually resolved the problem.

*PS: You can see on the issue's page that a solution is scheduled..*

Comment: We also asked the support and it turns out that the _pushaddress table on the backend side was temporariliy disconneted to the  mobilepush demographics,  and the issue was properly handeled by support. I think it's also relevant to the issues that you've mentioned. Thanks for sharing your experience :)

Comment: No worries. Don't hesitate to combine the two answers in one and mark it as answered